# awk script not able to change field separator

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following script taken from [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    if ($0 ~ /:/) {
        FS=":";
        $0=$0;
    } else {
        FS=" ";
        $0=$0
    } 
    print $3
}
```

input file

```
ONE 1 I
TWO 2 II
THREE:3:III
FOUR:4:IV
FIVE:5:V
SIX 6 VI
SEVEN 7 VII
```

my output

```
I
II

IV
V

VII
```

so my question is why is the 3rd field missing for some of the lines?

Comment: `$0=$0` is pointless. It doesn't force parsing line, you should normally use `$1=$1`.  However, it's not going to work in this case either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
{
    # force the FS
    if ($0 ~ /:/) FS=":"
     else FS=" "

    # force awk to retreat the field separation with "new" line content
    #  because this is done at the start of the loop once (so earlier than)
    #  new FS assignation
    $0 = $0

    # print the 3th field
    print $3
}
' YourFile
```

this is your original script adapted (difference are normaly not the source of your other result) tested on my aix and linux. Both give the 3th value correctly. On which system are you ?

Assuming your sample data structure (no mix of space or ":") you cna try (especialy for mac problem) using both separator at once via a class

```
awk -F '[: ]' '{ print $3 }' YourFile
```

Comment: im running the script on mac

Comment: another variant of the script is added in th reply

Answer (score 3):

you can set FS to both characters

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' '{print $3}' file
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: ]"} {print $3}' file
```

you can move the section between the single quotes to a script file, if that's what you want.

Comment: but how do I do that in a script?

Comment: this reply IS a script sample. if it should be inside the quoted source, use BEGIN section like second example but there is no reason for in your sample source

Answer (score 1):

In AWK scripts, the record and field separators are used to split the *next* field.  That's why they're usually set in a `BEGIN` clause.

If you need to split the current based on the contents of the current field, you'll have to use the `split` function, e.g.

```
arr_len = split($0, my_array, /:/);
if (arr_len > 3) {
    print my_array[3]
} else {
    ....
}
```

I would suggest the following quick reference to help:

[Shell Scripting Primer [How AWK-ward]](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/Howawk-ward/Howawk-ward.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-TP40003518-SW3)

Comment: maybe u wanna take a look at the link that i have provided, it is possible to change it dynamically.

Comment: See the comment later on that page: "However, this behavior changed in later versions, so the above script no longer works. What happens is that once the FS variable is changed, you have to re-evaluate the fields by using $0=$0:".  So I guess you can technically do it without using `split`, but it doesn't work automatically.  Also, I suspect that the "$0=$0:" syntax may be non-portable, whereas explicit use of `split` is portable.

Comment: are u able to provide a working example? sorry im still learning some of the caveats of awk scripting.

Comment: Done, though there are examples of split in the link above.  :-)